# Linkedin oAuth2 raises a value error, email required, Django

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am using LinkedIn OAuth in a Django app but not fetching an email address so it raises an email address error in the app.

It is set in settings.py as follows:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SCOPE = ['r_liteprofile', 'r_emailaddress',]
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_FIELD_SELECTORS = ['emailAddress', 'profilePicture']
-

SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_EXTRA_DATA = [
                               ('id', 'id'),
                               ('firstName', 'first_name'),
                               ('lastName', 'last_name'),
                               ('emailAddress', 'email_address'),
                               ('profilePicture', 'picture_url')
                               ]
```

What's missing here?

Comment: try using emailAddress instead of email-address in field_selectors

Comment: Tried again. Yes it is working. Thanks.

Comment: @Nalin Dobhal,  how can I render the profilePicture retrieved in Django?

Comment: which library  are you using for social auth?

Comment: I am using social-auth-app-django from https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django.